# position of axis multiplier and one other

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a question concerning the appearance of the multiplier above axis if `scaled ticks = true` is used.

I like to have two curves in one plot. The example shows my problem. I like to have scaled ticks above right axis but it appears above the left axis. Does anybody know how to fix it?

When I created this small example a second question occurs. Try to write 
`axis y line*=right` instead of `axis y line=right`. The label "y pos-right" moves to the left side an top of the "y pos-left". Any explanations for that and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
ylabel = y pos-left
]

\addplot[red] coordinates
{(-3,0) (-2,0.1) (-1,-0.6)
(0,1)
(1,-0.6) (2,0.1) (3,0)};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis y line=right,
scaled ticks = true,
xlabel = x pos-right,
ylabel = y pos
]

\addplot[blue] coordinates {(-3,-12000) (-2,11000)
(-1,-6000) (0,1000) (1,-100) (2,50) (3,0)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the scale label position is hard-coded to the upper left corner of the plot. If you set the option `ylabel near ticks`, however, this is corrected. It also fixes the incorrect placement of the `y label` when using `axis y line*=right`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
ylabel = y pos-left
]

\addplot[red] coordinates
{(-3,0) (-2,0.1) (-1,-0.6)
(0,1)
(1,-0.6) (2,0.1) (3,0)};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=right,
scaled  ticks = true,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel = x pos-right,
ylabel = y pos
]

\addplot[blue] coordinates {(-3,-12000) (-2,11000)
(-1,-6000) (0,1000) (1,-100) (2,50) (3,0)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is advisable to write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}` in your preamble - which also solves the problem: any value with version greater or equal to `compat=1.3` automatically activates `ylabel near ticks` for all figures in the plot.