# Pgfplot with two ordinates y tick base position

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [position of axis multiplier and one other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53029/position-of-axis-multiplier-and-one-other)

I have a plot with two ordinates. The tick base for the "right" y-axis is "10^-3". 
However, the "*10^-3" is placed on the left hand side. I would like to have it on the right hand side, as it belongs the right y-axis.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}}
\pgfplotsset{y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}} 
\pgfplotsset{y tick label style={/pgf/number format/precision=3}}

\newlength\plotheight
\newlength\plotwidth 
\setlength\plotheight{8cm}
\setlength\plotwidth{.8\textwidth} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \begin{axis}[
      width=\plotwidth,
      height=\plotheight,
      scale only axis,
      xmin=0, xmax=0.2,
      ymin=-0.002, ymax=0.002,
      every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{red}},
      axis y line=right,
      ]
      \addplot [color=red, solid, thick] 
      coordinates {(0,0) (0.1,0.001) (0.2,-0.001)};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[%
      width=\plotwidth,
      height=\plotheight,
      scale only axis,
      xmin=0, xmax=0.2,
      ymin=-0.2, ymax=0.2,
      every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{blue}},
      axis y line=left,
      xtick=\empty,
      ]
      \addplot [color=blue, solid, thick] 
      coordinates {(0,0) (0.1,0.06) (0.2,-0.15)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some dummy data using coordinates instead of your dat file? And please complete your code such that it starts from `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`. This would help others to directly copy your code and try out solutions.

Comment: @percusse Sorry, I have edited the code.

Comment: Solved, with the help of the above mentioned post.
I had pgfplots version 1.2.2. I have updated it to 1.6.1 and added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}` to the preamble. Thanks.