# How to move axis multiplier in a polar plot in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

How can I move the axis multiplier in a polar plot? In the following MWE, the axis multiplier is over the ticks and prevent the plot to be nice and readable.

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{4cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=1.0]
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
        axis on top,
        width = \figurewidth,
        height = \figureheight,
        scale only axis,
        ymin=5.e5, ymax=1.5e6,
        xtick      ={0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330},
        xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}6$, $\frac{\pi}3$, $\frac{\pi}2$, $\frac{2\pi}3$, $\frac{5\pi}6$, $\pi$ , $\frac{7\pi}6$, $\frac{4\pi}3$, $\frac{3\pi}2$, $\frac{5\pi}3$, $\frac{11\pi}6$},
        ytick = {5e5, 1.e6, 1.5e6},
    ]
    \addplot [data cs=polarrad, mark=*, draw=black, smooth]
        table [%
        col sep=comma, trim cells=true, %
        x=x, y=y,] %
        {mydata.dat};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The content of `mydata.dat` is as follows.

```
# mydata
x,y
0.0000,1.1686E+06
0.0175,1.1686E+06
0.0349,1.1446E+06
0.0524,1.1165E+06
0.0698,1.1034E+06
0.0873,1.1038E+06
0.1047,1.1059E+06
0.1222,1.1317E+06
0.1396,1.1500E+06
0.1571,1.1372E+06
0.1745,1.1173E+06
0.1920,1.1218E+06
0.2094,1.1257E+06
0.2269,1.1203E+06
0.2443,1.1078E+06
0.2618,1.1043E+06
0.2793,1.1239E+06
0.2967,1.1228E+06
0.3142,1.0912E+06
0.3316,1.0909E+06
```

The result is shown in the following figure. As can be seen `.10^6` is on the `xtick=0` and makes the plot hard to read.

[image]

I have run an update on all the packages including `pgfplots`. However, I still see `("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\pgfplots_1.7.tds\tex\generic\pgfplots\libs\
tikzlibrarypgfplots.polar.code.tex")` in the log file, which I assume it is using `compat=1.7`.

Regardless of the version, Which seems solvable, is there any way to manually set the position of the axis multiplier or at least fine tune its position?

Thanks.

Comment: I just ran your MWE exactly as posted, but the axis multiplier is in a different position (still not ideal location, but there must be other issues). My results: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vei9a.png

Comment: @PaulGessler: I fixed the problem with the version. Now I get similar results like the one you posted. Would it be possible to fine tune the axis multiplier in the picture you kindly posted? The reason I am asking this is that I have several plots similar to this with larger exponents for example `.10^16` which might lie on the ticks. Is there any way to shift the multiplier a little bit away from the plot? The following link shows the result for the larger multiplier: http://tinypic.com/r/2gxlpvp/8

Comment: The location is apparently hard-coded; see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53036/21344) for details (case is the same for polar axes). As Jake suggests, adding `ylabel near ticks` to the axis options will shift the multiplier. If this doesn't put the multiplier in an acceptable location, I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: @PaulGessler: thanks. It put it in another position which does not overlap with the ticks. However, I wish I could modify the position when I am not using `ylabel near ticks` as it places the multiplier in a great position and makes the plot super professional. I wish the position of axis multiplier could be fine-tuned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were looking for the `every y tick scale label/.style` option. I enclose an example.

```
%! *latex mal-polar-plot.tex
\documentclass[crop=true,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{4cm}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\def\malfile{mal-data.txt}
\begin{filecontents*}{\malfile}
# mydata
x,y
0.0000,1.1686E+06
0.0175,1.1686E+06
0.0349,1.1446E+06
0.0524,1.1165E+06
0.0698,1.1034E+06
0.0873,1.1038E+06
0.1047,1.1059E+06
0.1222,1.1317E+06
0.1396,1.1500E+06
0.1571,1.1372E+06
0.1745,1.1173E+06
0.1920,1.1218E+06
0.2094,1.1257E+06
0.2269,1.1203E+06
0.2443,1.1078E+06
0.2618,1.1043E+06
0.2793,1.1239E+06
0.2967,1.1228E+06
0.3142,1.0912E+06
0.3316,1.0909E+06
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=1.0]
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
        axis on top,
        width = \figurewidth,
        height = \figureheight,
        scale only axis,
        ymin=5.e5, ymax=1.5e6,
        xtick      ={0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330},
        xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}6$, $\frac{\pi}3$, $\frac{\pi}2$, $\frac{2\pi}3$, $\frac{5\pi}6$, $\pi$ , $\frac{7\pi}6$, $\frac{4\pi}3$, $\frac{3\pi}2$, $\frac{5\pi}3$, $\frac{11\pi}6$},
        ytick = {5e5, 1.e6, 1.5e6},
        every y tick scale label/.style={at={(0,1)}},
    ]
    \addplot [data cs=polarrad, mark=*, draw=black, smooth]
        table [%
        col sep=comma, trim cells=true, %
        x=x, y=y,] %
        {\malfile};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]