# change position of tick multiplier

Tags: pgfplots

I have a plot like this and want to change the position of the 'tick multiplier', i.e. change where the $10^{-3}$ or $10^{-4}$ actually occurs. I don't want to change where ticks occur or remove the scaling.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scaled ticks=true]
\addplot coordinates {
(20000,0.0005)
(40000,0.0010)
(60000,0.0020)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The placement of the scale labels is controlled using the `every [x/y/z] tick scale label` styles. Where do you want the scale labels to go?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163217/15925 should help

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me with: `every y tick scale label/.style={at={(0.075,0.975),left}}`